# Detect if my app runs in Azure

Tags: java, azure, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm wondering if it is possible to detect if my Java app inside a Docker container is running in Azure. For AWS it is pretty simple, because AWS has the EC2 meta data service (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). Has Azure something similar?

Thanks and Regards,
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://dl.windowsazure.com/javadoc/com/microsoft/windowsazure/serviceruntime/RoleEnvironment.html

Check out the isAvailable() method.